# How to define a PrimaryKeyPair for the database in C# (MVC)

Tags: c#, database-design, asp.net-mvc-3

I´m working with MVC3 in ASP .NET and stuck a little at the databasemodel.

I use the EntityFramework to create tables from my models. Now I want to define a PrimaryKey that depends from the MaterialID and the ListID. But how can I define it in C#?

Is there a Tag like [Key] to define that the PrimaryKey depends on more than one value?

[image: database diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework 4, you can specify a composite key in the constructor of your entity configuration like so:

```
HasKey(m => { m.MaterialID, m.ListID });
```